# iOS Swift: Prepare collectionView cell for reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm getting some unintended cell recycling behavior. I have a UICollectionView with custom cells, each of which contain a UITableView that can display one of two types of custom cells (imageCell or movieCell).

When the collectionView cells are recycled custom table view cells are not being dequeued properly. Instead the tableViewCell types are being inherited from the recycled cell.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    if tableView != nil {
        tableView = nil
    }
}
```

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @nhgrif said in his now deleted post, your code doesn't make much sense. (How come you deleted it?)

I would advise against deleting the table view and recreating it each time you recycle a collection view cell. Table views are big complex objects and creating and destroying them is pretty expensive.

Instead, leave the table view intact and simply send it a reloadData message. It should then reload itself with new contents.

If you **do** want to create and destroy your table view each time, make the instance variable you use to store the table view a weak optional variable. Then simply remove the table view from it's superview. That will cause it to be freed.

If you make your table view variable a weak optional, you'll need to create the table view in a strong local variable, add it to the superview, then save it into the weak instance variable. If you try to create your able view directly in the weak instance variable it will get deallocated before you can add it as a subview.

Comment: That makes sense. Reloading the tableView is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!